# CakePHP AuthComponent::login always return false

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, components

I can't login in my just new dev website base on CakePHP 2.5.
I use default identification, with AuthComponent::password, but every time, the function AuthAuthComponent::login return false, even if put right credentials in the form.

**AppController.php**

```
public $components = array(
    "DebugKit.Toolbar",
    "Session",
    "Auth" => array(
        "loginAction" => array(
            "controller" => "users",
            "action" => "login"
        ),
        "authError" => "Accès refusé"
    )
);
```

**UsersController.php**

```
public function manager_login() {
    $this->layout = "manager_login";

    // The user tries to connect
    if($this->request->is("post")) {
        if($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect("/manager/");
        }
    }
}
```

**User.php (Model) the beforeSave() function**

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    $this->data["User"]["password"] = AuthComponent::password($this->data["User"]["password"]);
}
```

manager_login.ctp (the view with the form)

```
<?php echo $this->form->create("User", array("inputDefaults" => array("div" => false, "label" => false))); ?>
    <div class="login-box-header bg-dark-blue">
        <h3 class="login-box-title">Administration</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="login-box-content bg-light-white">
        <?php echo $this->form->input("User.username"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->form->input("User.password"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->form->checkbox("User.remember"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->form->label("User.remember", "Se souvenir de moi"); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="login-box-footer" style="background-color: #fff">
        <button type="submit" class="tiny expand">Se connecter</button>
    </div>
<?php echo $this->form->end(); ?>
```

In fact, I think there is a problem with the SQL query because I don't see the WHERE condition in the following query :

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`email`,  
       `User`.`avatar`, `User`.`skype`, `User`.`twitter`, `User`.`created`, 
       `User`.`updated` 
FROM `leboncube`.`lbc_users` AS `User` 
WHERE `User`.`username` = 'Mike Hell' 
LIMIT 1
```

I hash the passwords on the users registration in the function beforeSave ; I compared the hash generated in the controller with $this->Auth->password and the hash in the database : they are strictly the same.

Comment: And the question is ... ?

Comment: Is the above code all you have in your controllers or ther are other methods you override? Maybe you wrote your own `isAuthorized` method?

Comment: The question is WHY AuthComponent::login always return false ?

Comment: No, there is no other method which are overridden.

Comment: Probably because you are already logged in. Don't *ever* call login() for an already logged in user. And your beforeSave() function is flawed. This way your passwords get flushed with empty strings hashed on each save.. Bad idea. See [working-with-passwords-in-cakephp](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/). Also note that `$this->form` != `$this->Form` (the latter is what you should use). Mind your casing for developing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem !
It was because I forgot to add the function isAuthorized() to my controller.

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: Where you added this. I have the same problem

Comment: AppController.php -> 

function isAuthorized($user) {
    return true;
  }